# Swing Timer on main(String[]) exits the program after the time specified

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer, actionlistener

I need to generate a new `Thread` every 2 seconds. So I tried to use the `Timer` class in the `main(String[])` method but my program just exists after the milliseconds I specified in the `Timer` constructor.

**Program.java**:

```
public class Program
{
    private static int panelWidth;
    private static int panelHeight;

    private static MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
        frame.add(Program.panel);

        Program.panelWidth = frame.getWidth();
        Program.panelHeight = frame.getHeight();

        Timer generateBallTimer = new Timer(2000, new GenerateBalls());
        while (true)
        {
            generateBallTimer.start();
        }



    } // End of main method


    /**
     * Generate a new ball every 2 seconds.
     *
     */
    public static class GenerateBalls implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Program.generateBalls();
        }
    }

    public static void generateBalls()
    {
        // Generate a ball each 2 seconds
        while (true)
        {
            Program.panel.balls.add(new Ball(Program.panel));
        }
    }



} // End of program class
```

If in the `Timer` constructor I will specify 3000ms my program will be closed after 3 seconds and so on.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Because of no answers I will just stay with my `while (true) {Thread.sleep(2000);}`

Comment: You should stop your habit of spreading `while (true)` loops all over you application. If your timer action never returns due to its `while (true)` loop, the Timer has no chance of calling it again. There’s also no point in doing `while (true) { generateBallTimer.start(); }`, once you’ve started the timer, attempting to start it again has no effect, besides burning the CPU with your loop.

Comment: And don’t give up just because there is no answer within the first few minutes.

Comment: @Holger Thanks man :). Although the `while (true){}` is essential in my game which needs to create more `Thread` balls every once and a while.

Comment: Re, "I need to generate a new Thread every 2 seconds."  No.  You don't.  Unless you are doing a homework assignment that explicitly says, "start a new thread every two seconds," then I can't believe that there is no better way to solve your problem.  What is your _real_ problem?  (i.e., what do you hope to accomplish with these threads?)

Comment: Biggest problem looks like `frame.setVisible(true);` is never called.  Without a visible frame, the program will exit when the main thread terminates.  So show the frame, and get rid of the `while(true){ }`.

Comment: @jameslarge I just want to generate a new ball to be spawned for my game.

Comment: @AJNeufeld `frame.setVisible(true);` is in MyFrame class.

Comment: Using a separate thread to represent the state of each animated object on your screen is very limiting.  Better to represent that state with simple objects stored in a _display list_, and then have a single thread or timer task that periodically computes new states for all of the objects in the list and signals the UI thread to re-paint the screen.

Comment: @jameslarge Sounds interesting. As far as I know,for all the `Object`s in a game to work concurrently they need to be `Thread`s. Can you give me example of that "display list"?

Comment: What you probably want is something close to https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7d9e84edf2e36c580e471443d39f6967 - you can not have infinite loops in swing, you have to use endlessly repeating timers (like you almost did). There are also not actually threads created. It all runs within the swing ["Event Dispatch Thread"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Comment: @zapl Wow. very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you give me example of that "display list"?

You talk about "balls".  What does your program need to know about a ball?  Probably its position, maybe its speed, maybe its mass.  Size? color? other stuff?  It's up to you.  The simplest implementation of a `Ball` object would just be a class with `public` fields to hold all of that information.  Then, if `Ball` is the only kind of moving object in your animation, then your display list could just be a `List<Ball>`.

In a more complicated program, your `Ball` class might be an extension of some more general class, maybe `VisibleObject`, and then your display list would be a `List<VisibleObject>`.

> As far as I know,for all the objects in a game to work concurrently they need to be `Thread`s.

In a sense, you are right because there is only one class in all of Java that can do any work at all, and that class is `Thread`.  No other class actually ever *does* anything.  Other classes merely define methods that can be called *by* threads.

The trick is, to decouple the threads in the program from the work that they do.  That's the motivation for the `Runnable` interface.  Instead of having one object that both *is* a thread and also, describes the work to be *done* by the thread, you can have two classes;  One takes care of all the thread-y stuff (.start(), .interrupt(), .join(), ...), and the other describes the work to be done (.run()).

Some say, it's hard to write a program that has too many classes/objects, but it's easy to write one that has too few.

As long as your `Ball` objects or your `VisibleObject` objects cleanly describe the things that you want to see on the screen and the ways in which you want to see those things move, there's no reason why each one's methods must be called by its own dedicated thread.  There's no reason why you can't have just *one* thread that does the calculations for each one in its turn.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I'm completely don't know how to implement what you describe here. Maybe when I will learn some more.